# How to upload RecordRTC blob file to Rails paperclip in AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, file-upload, blob, getusermedia

On the client side, the user uses [RecordRTC](https://webrtc-experiment.appspot.com/RecordRTC/) to record a short video. When the user presses upload, I will get the video's `blob` data using `recorder.getBlob()`, and upload it to my server (using Rails and [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) to handle file upload).

At first, I wanted to change the `<input type='file'>` field value to the `blob` data. It turns out that for security in browsers, I cannot change it using javascript.

Then, I tried to use AJAX:

```
$("#ajax-submit").on("click", function() {
    var data = new FormData();

    data.append("record[video]", recorder.getBlob(), (new Date()).getTime() + ".webm");

    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("POST", "/records/");
    oReq.send(data);
    oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
        if (oReq.status == 200) {
            console.log("Uploaded");
        } else {
            console.log("Error " + oReq.status + " occurred uploading your file.");
        }
    };
});
```

**However, it does not work.** On `log` file, I will get the following, which cannot be handled:

```
Processing by RecordsController#create as */*
Parameters: {
  "video"=>"data:video/webm;base64,GkXfo0AgQoaBAUL3gQFC8o..."
}
```

If I submit normally using `form`, I will have parameters look like this:

```
Processing by RecordsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {
    "video"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x3b476e0 @original_filename="testing.mp4", @content_type="video/mp4", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"record[video]\"; filename=\"testing.mp4\"\r\nContent-Type: video/mp4\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:a_path>>
}
```

How could I solve the problem?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, the cause of problem is that the `blob` file returned from `recorder.getBlob()` is not an actual `blob`. Refer to the answer from [muaz-khan](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/issues/8#issuecomment-19252169).

I added the following lines in RecordRTC to get the real `blob` and do the same AJAX submitted. Everything work now.

```
         getBlob: function () {
             return blobURL2;
         },
+        getRealBlob: function() {
+            return blobURL;
+        },
```

Comment: can you share this source code :( the controller with the erb file ?

Answer (score 2):

I handled kind of same problem in one of my project. The situation was the API has to convert a blob data to image file that was being sent by a mobile device. I am assuming the action to be upload in your controller file.

```
def upload
  #extract the video data from params
  video = params[:video]

  # define the save path for the video. I am using public directory for the moment. 
  save_path = Rails.root.join("public/videos/#{video.original_filename}")

  # Open and write the file to file system.
  File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |f|
    f.write params[:video].read
  end

  render :nothing => true
end
```

Comment: Thanks. It is not the problem in controller. I solved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17059174/889972).