# Rails 4: How to upload a javascript Blob?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, paperclip

I'm building a Rails app that uses client-side javascript to edit an image and produce a [Blob](http://www.javascripture.com/Blob) containing the data for the newly created image. I'm using the Paperclip gem to manage storing images on the server-side. I know how to upload images using Rails and Paperclip via traditional forms. But how do I upload this Blob? I would prefer an AJAX solution.

Comment: Possible duplication: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17037660/how-to-upload-recordrtc-blob-file-to-rails-paperclip-in-ajax